# C# Selenium Webdriver JavaScriptExecutor Prompt Window

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a JavaScript Prompt Window which I am trying to handle. I had one previously that was simply contained an 'OK' and 'Cancel' which I was able to handle with

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)ts.getDriver()).ExecuteScript("window.confirm = function(){return true; }")
```

However now I have another prompt message but this time it requires me to send text to the prompt message and then hit 'OK'. I am not real familiar with javascript and the syntax can anyone supply the syntax to hand sending the text to the prompt box?

UPDATE: The application I am trying to automate has generated a Windows Prompt. In the past I have handled most of the alert pop ups with

```
.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

However this particular Windows Prompt (Please see image example)

[image]

cannot be captured this way hence my use of JavaScript to handle the window Pop Up. The reason I referenced the first section of code at the top was because this particular piece of code I used to handle the first Window Prompt. The difference being this time the Windows Prompt Box has an 'OK' Button, a 'Cancel' Button AND a text box in it which I must enter some sort of text to close the prompt box. All I am trying to find out is what syntax am I using to handle sending text into this Windows prompt for example:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)ts.getDriver()).ExecuteScript("window.confirm = function(){return true; }");
```

was used to close out the 'OK' prompt message but for a prompt box with text what should I be writing inside of the ExecuteScript

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)ts.getDriver()).ExecuteScript("???");
```

So basically what script should I be writing where the question marks are.

Comment: Please read how to ask.

Comment: [How To Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There's very little information to work with here, consider posting more of your code.

Comment: I made an update please read above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this must be a pretty common use case for Selenium; my experience is limited. Googling around, however, I found the following:

```
Alert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().SendKeys("Hello");
alert.Accept();
```

(From [SeleniumEasy](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-handle-javascript-alerts-confirmation-prompts))

I fixed the camel case for the C# implementation; the original example is in Java.

Comment: Thank you I realized that this prompt box actually allowed me to use the alert method but i'd still be curious if someone could show me how to implement text for JavaScriptExecutor

Comment: Yeah I am not sure how you would do that, given that it's outside the page. I'm surprised your `confirm`/`return true` code worked.